# Не могу удалить запись из базы sql в remove_shop

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql

```
class database:

    def __init__(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        sql = db.cursor()
        sql.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (name TEXT, sell TEXT, opis TEXT)')

    def get_shop(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        sql = db.cursor()

        sql.execute("SELECT * FROM shop")
        mas_ret = []
        for i in sql.fetchall():
            print(i)
            mas_ret.append(i)
        return mas_ret


    def add_shop(self, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        sql = db.cursor()
        shop = (kwargs['name'], kwargs['count'], kwargs['opis'])
        sql.execute("INSERT INTO shop (name, sell, opis) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", shop)
        print('Запись прошла успешно!')
        db.commit()


    def remove_shop(self, name):
        print(name)
        db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        sql = db.cursor()
        print('уже тут')
        sql.execute("DELETE FROM shop WHERE name="+ (name)
        print('Удаление прошло успешно!')
        db.commit()

('New', '20', 'Нету')
```

уже тут

```
Command raised an exception: OperationalError: no such column: New
```

Пробовал `sql.execute('DELETE FROM shop WHERE name=?, name)`, тоже не помогло

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (ссылка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: sql.execute('DELETE FROM shop WHERE name=?", (name,)) - так не работает?

Comment: ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.

Comment: а, я запятую не поставил, заработало

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста )